# How do I merge ranged elements in a list?

Tags: python

```
testlist = ["13A", "13B", "13C", "23D", "5D", "9B", "9C", "9D"]
```

What I want the list to be:

```
["13A-C", "23D", "5D", "9B-D"]
```

Bonus points if you can sort it (5,9,13,23).

For those interested, this is my current WIP script:

```
testlist = ["13A", "13B", "13C", "23D", "5D", "9B", "9C", "9D"]
newlist = []

lenlist = len(testlist)

for i in range(lenlist):
    
    #check values of first
    indexnum = testlist[i][:-1]
    indexchar = testlist[i][-1]    


    if i == 0:
        newlist.append(testlist[i])

    if indexnum == (testlist[i-1][:-1]):
        newlistvalue = (indexnum + (testlist[i-1][-1]) + "-" + (testlist[i][-1]))
        if ((indexchar == "B") and ((testlist[i-1][-1]) == "A")) or ((indexchar == "D") and ((testlist[i-1][-1]) == "C")):
            newlist.append(newlistvalue)
        lastval = newlist[len(newlist)-1][-1]
        lastval2 = newlist[(len(newlist)-2)]
        #print(lastval2)
        if (indexchar == "C") and (lastval == "B"):
            newlistvalue = lastval2[:-1] + indexchar
            #print(newlistvalue)
            newlist.pop()
            newlist.pop()
            #print(newlistvalue)
            newlist.append(newlistvalue)
        else:
            newlist.append(testlist[i])
            
print (newlist)
#print (newlistvalue)
```

Comment: not enough details for edge cases... also please show us what have you tried even if it awkwardly wrong..  :)

Comment: Start by creating a dictionary whose keys are the number prefixes and values are a sorted list of the letters. Then you can turn the sorted list into a range of `start-end`, and concatenate it to the number.

Comment: Bonus points? You can get them when you show your attempt, and indicate what the problem is in getting the desired result.

Comment: Add more details and it will be nice if you share what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to create a dict of the numbers and letters, I assume there will only be one letter in each string. Then you need to sort it and format it. You can use the following:

```
pairs = defaultdict(list)
for s in testlist:
    pairs[s[:-1]].append(s[-1])
result = [f'{k}{"-".join(dict.fromkeys([v[0], v[-1]]))}'
             for k, v in sorted(pairs.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]
```

---

```
['5D', '9B-D', '13A-C', '23D']
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that each string in the list ends with exactly one letter, you could do this:

```
import re

testlist = ["13A", "13C", "13B", "23D", "5D", "9B", "9C", "9D"]

def seq(lst):
    return lst[0] if len(lst) == 1 else f'{lst[0]}-{lst[-1]}'

def key(e):
    return int(re.search('\d+', e)[0])

d = {}

for e in testlist:
    d.setdefault(int(e[:-1]), []).append(e[-1])

print(sorted([f'{k}{seq(sorted(v))}' for k, v in d.items()], key=key))
```

**Output:**

```
['5D', '9B-D', '13A-B', '23D']
```

**Note:**

Subtle change to OP's data to show that this code can handle out-of-sequence values